# Use tf.gather to extract tensors row-wise based on another tensor row-wisely (first dimension)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have two tensors with dimensions as `A:[B,3000,3]` and `C:[B,4000]` respectively. I want to use `tf.gather()` to use every single row from tensor C as index, and to use every row from tensor A as params, to get a result with size `[B,4000,3]`.

Here is an example to make this more understandable: Say I have tensors as

> A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
>
> C = [0,2,1,2,1],
>
> result = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[4,5,6]],

by using `tf.gather(A,C)`. It is all fine when applying to tensors with dimension less than 3.

But when it is the case as the description as the beginning, by applying `tf.gather(A,C,axis=1)`, the shape of result tensor is

> [B,B,4000,3]

It seems that `tf.gather()` just did the job for every element in tensor C as the indices to gather elements in tensor A. The only solution I am thinking about is to use a `for` loop, but that would extremely reduce the computational ability by using `tf.gather(A[i,...],C[i,...])` to gain the correct size of tensor

> [B,4000,3]

Thus, is there any function that is able to do this task similarly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = ...  # B x 3000 x 3
C = ...  # B x 4000
s = tf.shape(C)
B, cols = s[0], s[1]
# Make indices for first dimension
idx = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(B, dtype=C.dtype), 1), [1, cols])
# Complete index for gather_nd
gather_idx = tf.stack([idx, C], axis=-1)
# Gather result
result = tf.gather_nd(A, gather_idx)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you! It is somehow hard for me to understand. Please tell me if I am wrong. 'idx' gives index to each row (first dimension), and 'gather_idx' gives index to the 4000 elements in each 'idx', such that the 'Bx4000x2' gives the entire index for A? What is the actual meaning of the third dimension in 'gather_idx' (Bx4000x2)? Does it mean the global index represented by element ID in B and element ID in 4000?

Comment: @KayeeJoe You can think of `A` as a collection of 3-vectors, each of which is at some specific coordinates `(i, j)` in the tensor. In `tf.gather_nd`, the last dimension of `gather_idx` represent these two coordinates from `A`. So if `gather_idx` has shape `(B, 4000, 2)` it means you will get a "matrix of 3-vectors" with shape `(B, 4000, 3)` such that the 3-vector at position `(r, s)` in the result will be `A[gather_idx[r, s, 0], gather_idx[r, s, 1]]`. In your case, the input `C` only gives you the second index, and with `idx` you get the full two-dimensional index for `tf.gather_nd`.